# Using grep and regex to get specific users list from etc/password

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to grab specific users ID from the `/etc/passwd` file in bash.

A given user ID is made of exactly 6 characters, either 6 integers or 1 letter and 5 integers (the letter is always the first character of the user ID in the second case). See example below:

```
398329
y32839
392009
r39288
```

I am looking for a regex pattern to get a list with only the user IDs that match this format, from my `/etc/passwd` file. This is what I did so far:

```
users="$(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep -o '[0-9]*')"
```

I could get the user IDs with numbers but since my regex is limited, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` with correct regex like this:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]{5}$'
398329
y32839
392009
r39288
```

`^[a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]{5}$` will match username of 6 digits or a letter followed by 5 digits.

**As an improvement**, you can replace `cut + grep` with this single `awk` command:

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]{5}$/{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

grep with perl regex:

```
grep -oP '\w:\d{5}' /etc/passwd
```

example results:

```
4:65534
x:65534
```

I assume you're referring to the password encrypted field in etc/passwd, which is separated with colon; but if you really only concerned with UIDs that actually begin with a letter then simply remove the second colon in the regex, `'\w\d{5}'`.